# Removing rows in data.frame having columns subsumed in others

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to achieve something similar to `unique` in a data.frame where column each element of a column in a row are vectors. What I want to do is if the elements of the vector in the column of that hat row a subset or equal to another remove the row with smaller number of elements. I can achieve this with a nested `for` loop but since data contains 400,000 rows the program is very inefficient.

**Sample data**

```
# Set the seed for reproducibility 
set.seed(42)

# Create a random data frame
mydf <- data.frame(items = rep(letters[1:4], length.out = 20), 
                   grps = sample(1:5, 20, replace = TRUE),
                   supergrp =  sample(LETTERS[1:4], replace = TRUE))


# Aggregate items into a single column
temp <- aggregate(items ~ grps + supergrp, mydf, unique)

# Arrange by number of items for each grp and supergroup 
indx <- order(lengths(temp$items), decreasing = T)
temp <- temp[indx, ,drop=FALSE]
```

Temp looks like

```
       grps supergrp   items
    1     4        D a, c, d
    2     3        D    c, d
    3     5        D    a, d
    4     1        A       b
    5     2        A       b
    6     3        A       b
    7     4        A       b
    8     5        A       b
    9     1        D       d
   10     2        D       c
```

Now you can see that second combination of supergrp and items in second and third row is contained in first row. So, I want to delete the second and third rows from the result. Similarly, rows 5 to 8 are contained in row 4. Finally, rows 9 and 10 are contained in the first row, so I want to delete rows 9 and 10. 
Hence, my result would look like:

```
      grps supergrp   items
    1    4        D a, c, d
    4    1        A       b
```

My implementation is as follows::

```
# initialise the result dataframe by first row of old data frame
newdf <-temp[1, ]

# For all rows in the the original data
for(i in 1:nrow(temp))
{
  # Index to check if all the items are found 
  indx <- TRUE

  # Check if item in the original data appears in the new data
  for(j in 1:nrow(newdf))
  {
   if(all(c(temp$supergrp[[i]], temp$items[[i]]) %in% 
          c(newdf$supergrp[[j]], newdf$items[[j]]))){
     # set indx to false if a row with same items and supergroup  
     # as the old data is found in the new data
    indx <- FALSE
   }
  }

  # If none of the rows in new data contain items and supergroup in old data append that
  if(indx){
    newdf <- rbind(newdf, temp[i, ])
  }
}
```

I believe there is an efficient way to implement this in R; may be using the `tidy` framework and `dplyr` chains but I am missing the trick. Apologies for a longish question. Any input would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a network/graph problem. You could use the `igraph` package to find a graph linking each of the `grp/supergrp` pairings to `items`, then you could assign a 'cluster' to each group to determine which `items` are shared.

Comment: Not a full answer, but you can assign these cluster identifiers like `library(igraph);
int <- interaction(mydf[c("grps","supergrp")]);
g <- graph.data.frame(cbind(mydf["items"],int));
clg <- clusters(g);
mydf$clusters <- clg$membership[match(int, names(clg$membership))]` for example.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to get the items out of a list column and store them in a longer dataframe. Here is my somewhat hacky solution:

```
library(stringr)

items <- temp$items %>% 
    map(~str_split(., ",")) %>% 
    map_df(~data.frame(.))

out <- bind_cols(temp[, c("grps", "supergrp")], items)

out %>% 
    gather(item_name, item, -grps, -supergrp) %>% 
    select(-item_name, -grps) %>% 
    unique() %>% 
    filter(!is.na(item))
```

Comment: Is there a way to sneak in the `grps` field in the result.

Comment: I think so you can use `distinct(supergrp, item)` instead of `unique()`